# How to export Adf pipelines,dataflows,datasets into Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have 100 dataflows ,50 pipelines and their related datasets variables etc.
Now i want to use Synapse service and want my all pipelines amd stuff of ADF into Synapse. My Adf is git configured
Can we export them in one go??

Comment: I would leave them there, if there is no great need to move them. Please check that your ADF features are available in Synapse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-integration/concepts-data-factory-differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move data from data factory to synapse we need to download the supported module files in ADF.

[image]

I tried to migrate data from ADF to Synapse workspace using PowerShell following below procedure:

I connected to Azure account using below command:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

I set my subscription using below command:

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "<SubscriptionName>"
```

[image]

I created a linked service for source and sink using below comand:

```
Set-AzSynapseLinkedService -WorkspaceName <synapseworkspace> -Name <linkedservicename> -DefinitionFile "<json file path>"
```

I created dataset for source and sink in synapse workspace using below command:

```
Set-AzSynapseDataset  -WorkspaceName <synapseworkspace> -Name <datasetname> -DefinitionFile "<json file path>"
```

I created pipeline in synapse workspace using below command:

```
Set-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName <synapseworkspace> -Name <pipelinename> -DefinitionFile "<json file path>"
```

They are created successfully in synapse workspace:

[image]

In your case you are having bulk data in your data factory, you can use Azure Data Factory to Synapse Analytics Migration Tool.

You can migrate Azure Data Factory pipelines, datasets, linked service, integration runtime and triggers to a Synapse Workspace through below PowerShell script:

```
  .\importADFtoSynapseTool.ps1 -sourceADFResourceId "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourcegroups/<ADFResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<ADFName>" -destSynapseResourceId "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourcegroups/<SynapseResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/<SynapseName>" -TenantId <tenantId>
```

- Resource group name for Azure Data Factory
- Resource group name for Azure Synapse Workspace
- Subscription ID
- Tenant ID (you can find this by click Azure Active Directory in the Azure Portal)

For more clarification you can visit [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse/tree/main/Pipelines/ImportADFtoSynapse).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this out of the box.
There is an option to download the object's JSON and then use PowerShell to recreate the objects in Synapse workspace.
I haven't tried that myself, but the process is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403992/azure-data-factory-v2-arm-template-to-synpase-data?childtoview=404618#answer-404618).